# UIWebView alert not display page URL?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I am using a UIWebview in my app, and when there is an error, it displays an alert message.

The message is fine, but the title of the alert message displays the page URL, which doesn't help.

Anyway to get rid of that and display a custom text instead?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the implementation of the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocoll where 
`- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error` is defined. There you should set an `UIAlertView` with `- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message delegate:(id)delegate cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, I am not looking for loading error. I would like display a message, not necessarily an error.

Comment: There are several other methods in UIWebViewDelegate for reactiing before or after loading a webview. This may help you.